# Change font-size in html Window in wxPython

Tags: python, html, wxpython

I am including a html file into my app. However, if I change the font-size in my html for a paragraph, it is not shown in my app. The font-size is still the same for all paragraphs. Is there anything I am forgetting?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 font-family="arial, sans-serif">{TITLE}</h2>
<p>{AUTHORS}</p>
<p>{JOURNAL}</p>
<br>
<br>
<p style="font-size: 16pt">{ABSTRACT}</p>
<br>
<p>{KEYWORDS}</p>
<p>{DOI}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, what will be filled in for the abstract is supposed to be bigger than the other paragraphs. The size in my app however is the same for each paragraph.

I am setting up my html in the app as follows:

```
class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Main, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self.panel, -1, size=(800, 800))
        self.html.SetStandardFonts()
        self.html.SetPage(html_from_file)
```

How do you effectively change the font-size of a text in a wxPython html window?

Comment: I found that it is possible to set a font size in SetStandardFonts(), e.g. SetStandardFonts(13). However, this is not as flexible as specifying the style in the html itself and I would still prefer a solution that allows to do this.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this?
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html.HtmlWindow.html#wx.html.HtmlWindow.SetFonts

Comment: @DanA.S. Yes, this is how I got it to work in the end. I am still wondering if wxpython ignores all/most of my styling in the html file?

Comment: From docs: Note If you want complete HTML/CSS support as well as a Javascript engine, consider using wx.html2.WebView instead.
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html2.WebView.html#wx-html2-webview

Comment: Thank you very much! Have not seen than yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing from @DanA.S.:

I used

```
self.html = wx.html2.WebView.New(self.panel, -1, size=(800, 800), style=wx.html.HW_SCROLLBAR_AUTO)
```

and later

```
self.html.SetPage(my_html_str, "")
```

to setup my html component. This allowed me to specify all the formatting in my source html file.